# SQL error returned after attempting to create a magento category using xmlrpc in Python

Tags: python, sql, magento, xml-rpc

So I am trying to programmatically create a Magento category in Python using the xmlrpc API.
I am new to Python, this is my first serious program I am writing in Python.
I do not know for sure if this has something to do with my code but I'll give it a try.
This is my code:

```
from xmlrpc import client as cl
import pprint

proxy = cl.ServerProxy('http://example.com/index.php/api/xmlrpc/', allow_none=True)

session = proxy.login('api_user','api_key')

#PARAMS

name = 'Python Category'
path = ''
description = 'Inserted with my app'
meta_title = 'Python Category'
meta_keywords = 'Cool , Cat'
meta_description = 'Search robots will find this'
landing = ''
display = ''
active = 1
layout = ''
listing = {
    'name' : name,
    'is_active' : active,
    'position' : 1,
    'available_sort_by' : None,
    'custom_design' : None,
    'custom_apply_to_products' : None,
    'custom_design_from' : None,
    'custom_design_to' : None,
    'custom_layout_update' : None,
    'default_sort_by' : None,
    'description' : description,
    'display_mode' : display,
    'is_anchor' : 0,
    'landing_page' : landing,
    'meta_description' : meta_description,
    'meta_keywords' : meta_keywords,
    'meta_title' : meta_title,
    'page_layout' : '',
    'url_key' : path,
    'include_in_menu' : 1}

pprint.pprint(proxy.call(session, 'catalog_category.create', [listing]))
```

So I have some doubts about
 `pprint.pprint(proxy.call(session, 'catalog_category.create', [listing]))`

I have no clue what I am doubting about but having listing inside array seems unnatural to me.

So my code is generating this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Eigenaar\Desktop\connect.py", line 44, in <module>
    pprint.pprint(proxy.call(session, 'catalog_category.create', [listing]))
  File "C:\Users\Eigenaar\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35-32\lib\xmlrpc\client.py", line 1091, in __call__
    return self.__send(self.__name, args)
  File "C:\Users\Eigenaar\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35-32\lib\xmlrpc\client.py", line 1431, in __request
    verbose=self.__verbose
  File "C:\Users\Eigenaar\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35-32\lib\xmlrpc\client.py", line 1133, in request
    return self.single_request(host, handler, request_body, verbose)
  File "C:\Users\Eigenaar\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35-32\lib\xmlrpc\client.py", line 1149, in single_request
    return self.parse_response(resp)
  File "C:\Users\Eigenaar\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35-32\lib\xmlrpc\client.py", line 1321, in parse_response
    return u.close()
  File "C:\Users\Eigenaar\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35-32\lib\xmlrpc\client.py", line 654, in close
    raise Fault(**self._stack[0])
xmlrpc.client.Fault: <Fault 1: "SQLSTATE[21000]: Cardinality violation: 1241 Operand should contain 1 column(s), query was: SELECT `mg_catalog_category_entity`.* FROM `mg_catalog_category_entity` WHERE (entity_id ='Cool , Cat', 'Python Category', 'Search robots will find this', '', '', 'Python Category', 1, '', '', 0, '', '', '', '', 1, 'Inserted with my app', '', '', '', 1)">
```

I think it may also have something to do with the values that I am trying to insert.
Any advice would be appreciated. Amazing guides for Python is no exception!

Answer (score 0):

This has NOTHING to do with Python. Your SQL is bad:

```
... WHERE (entity_id ='Cool , Cat', 'Python Category', ..
```

You cannot use an equality test (`=`) to test MULTIPLE values at the same time. That's a flat-out syntax error.

It should be

```
... WHERE entity_id IN ('Cool Cat', 'Python Category', etc...
```

Comment: Hmm... That is kind of awkward. So I am assuming this has something to do with Magento its self? Because I don't create a SQL what so ever. I just use the Magento method.